# Using PHP while loop on a dynamic page won't work

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to show it all with while loop on a dynamic page, but it wont show anything at all..

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
      $genre = $_GET['id'];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM movstream_genre WHERE ID = '$genre'";
      $result = $db->query($sql);
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
}else{
     $sql = "SELECT ID, genre FROM movstream_genre";
     $result = $db->query($sql);
}

<html>
<body>
<ul>
    <?php while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ): ?>
    <li><a href="genre?id=<?=$row['ID'];?>"><?=$row['genre'];?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know why it wont show anything on the dynamic page, but if the page is not dynamic it works fine :)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors, it just wont show anything from the db when its on a dynamic page.

Comment: var_dump($row) ,to see whether values are coming or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$genre = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT ID, genre FROM movstream_genre";
$result = $db->query($sql);
}
```

This it how it needs to look when its a dynamic page :)
well i think it is, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

If dynamic page means that your sending an `id` in Url an you are not getting result.
I think that the problem is that you are using `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` in `if` condition and also in while.
Please use fetching in one place. Better be in while loop.
Hope it helps.

Comment: It was allmost that :D now it only shows the id that the dynamic page is on if you know what i mean :)
I want it to show all the id's.
Its an sub menu that show all the 'genre' Action, Crime etc.

Comment: @krunos, so, do you want to show an entire list of genres regardless the `id` parameter set or not? In this case you, probably, don't need to write the if/else block in that manner. Just fetch all needed data from DB. And if the `id` parameter is set, take it from that list. Alternatively, you can make an additional request to DB instead of searching the needed item in the previously fetched list.

Comment: Do you want to show all the genre and highlight the given one?

Answer (score 0):

please echo the result ...

```
<li><a href="genre?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['genre'];?></a></li>
```

And in href, it is only genre OR genre.php

In the first query..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movstream_genre WHERE ID = '$genre'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();// this line not required
```

comment this line
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't enclosed the first part of your PHP code in `<?php` `?>` tags

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i forgot to copy it in here :D